# Understanding field automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field, automorphism-group

I am studying splitting fields, but have realized that I have a conceptual gap when it comes to field automorphisms. More specifically, if $F$ is a field and $\overline{F}$ is its algebraic closure so that $F\leq E\leq\overline{F}$ where $E$ is a finite algebraic field extension. I understand that there are only a finite number of automorphisms of $E$ leaving $F$ fixed, but if we only look at $F$, is there a finite amount of automorphisms just over $F$ as well without thinking about any extensions. Is there any sense to studying field automorphisms unless that specific field is a finite algebraic extension of some other field?

Comment: What do you mean with "automorphisms just over $F$"? Try to be as precise as possible.

Comment: I guess in the sense of viewing $F$ as a prime field and studying the members of Aut$(F)$. Does that group contain more elements than the identity map?

Comment: @Mika Seeing Aut$\;(F)\;$ in the fields extension $\;F_F\;$ then yes: that is a group with only one element...whether $\;F\;$ is a prime field or not.

Comment: Your answer is again ambiguous. The term "prime field" indicates that you consider automorphisms that fix $F$; but then the question is: automorphisms of what? The notation $\mathrm{Aut}(F)$ indicates that you means automorphisms of $F$. But these are just the automorphisms that fix the prime field (i.e. $\mathbb F_p$, for a prime $p$, or $\mathbb Q$) contained in $F$. Are you then asking about what one can say about these automorphisms if $F$ is not finite over its prime field?

Comment: @Claudius I think what I had trouble seeing was that any member of Aut$(F)$ necessearily must leave the prime field of $F$ fixed and so if $F$ is a prime field to begin with, then the only member of Aut$(F)$ is the identity map. And just to see if my understanding is correct: if $F$ is not a prime field, but a finite extension of its underlying prime field then the number automorphism would be depended upon the underlying degree of the irreducible polynomials?

Comment: I don't know of which irreducible polynomial you speak. But it is true that if $F$ is finite over its prime field, say $F_0$, then the number of automorphisms of $F$ is at most $[F:F_0]$ (the dimension of $F$ as an $F_0$-vector space). If $F$ has positive characteristic then this is always an equality.

Comment: Aha, that makes sense. I haven't gotten to seperable extensions just yet, but what you say does make intuitive sense, so thank you. What I meant by irreducible polynomials was that if the underlying prime field was isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$, and the extension field is $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ for example. Then the underlying irreducible polynomial has degree 2 and so the degree of the extension, and hence number of automorphisms, is 2 as well.

Comment: I see. Just a small nitpick: there is no "underlying irreducible polynomial" of a field extension. It depends on a chosen generator. For example, $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}) = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}+1)$, but $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}+1$ have different minimal polynomials over $\mathbb Q$.